# Mutation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, this

In the below code `size2()` method working fine.But in `size1()` it is mutating the object and making it null.why such behavior is not happening in `size2()`?

```
class Node {
    constructor(data, next = null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    insert(data) {
        this.head = new Node(data, this.head);
    }

    size1() {
        var counter = 0;
        while (this.head) {
            counter++;
            this.head = this.head.next;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    size2() {
        var counter = 0;
        var node = this.head;
        while (node) {
            counter++;
            node = node.next;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
var list = new LinkedList();
list.insert(35);

console.log(list);
console.log(list.size2());
```

To me both the method looks same. Is there any subtle difference in those methods?

Comment: its because by the time you've called size2 its on next therefore null

Comment: In the size2() method because of using the variable node mutation is not      happening why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `size2()`, you are not mutating `this.head` because you first copy the reference in a local variable. Since in the `while` loop you are mutating the local `node = node.next` starting here `node`and `this.head` are not linked any more. It's the eternal **Value/Reference pitfall**.

Here is a [related article](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0?gi=f219cfcc51d7).